# How can I access this nested array within my JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, arrays, object

I'm using PHP to return a json_encode()'d array for use in my Javascript code. It's being returned as:

```
{"parent1[]":["child1","child2","child2"],"parent2[]":["child1"]}
```

By using the following code, I am able to access `parent2 > child1`

```
$.getJSON('myfile.php', function(data)
{
   for (var key in data)
   {
      alert(data[key]);
   }
}
```

However, this doesn't give me access to `child1, child2, child`, of `parent1`. Alerting the key by itself shows 'parent1' but when I try to alert it's contents, I get undefined.

I figured it would give me an object/array? How do I access the children of parent1?

data[key][0] ?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON returned should be:

```
{"parent1":["child1","child2","child2"],"parent2":["child1"]}
```

then you can access them as:

```
var data = {"parent1":["child1","child2","child2"],"parent2":["child1"]}
alert(data['parent1'][0]);
alert(data['parent1'][1]);
alert(data['parent1'][2]);
```

Comment: Unless my eyes deceive me, the only difference there is you've renamed parent1[] to parent1 and parent2[] to parent2. How would this fix the code? :/ The 'parents' are the names of inputs within my HTML form. The inputs are arrays and, therefor, are named with [].

Comment: OK, so you don't have to rename as I did.  But you can still access them as: 
    
    for (var i = 0; i < data['parent1[]'].length; i++) {
       alert( data['parent1[]'][i]); 
    }

Answer (score 1):

You're only iterating one level into the object, so it's correct that you're only seeing the parents.  You'll need to descend into those keys to find the children.

```
// Generally, avoid the "foreach" form in JavaScript.
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  alert(data[i]); // Parent1[], Parent2[], etc

  var parent = data[i];

  for (var j = 0; j < parent.length; j++) {
    alert(parent[j]); // Child1, Child2, etc
  }
}
```

Aside, the [] suffix on Parent keys is okay.  It *is* valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign it in a variable as follows:

var  = data[key];

and then get the contents of the array by using the size of the array.

Hope that helps.